# htaccess manipulation to merge two different RewriteRule blocks

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to merge two different `.htaccess` blocks.

1. for hiding `*.php` extension:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

2. for redirecting to specific web is string matched with MySQL row:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ friendly_url.php?friendly_url=$1
```

If one works, other gets blocked, for example this way works friendly_url, but it doesn't hide PHP extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ friendly_url.php?friendly_url=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

My php code contains simple query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM url WHERE friendly_url ='$friendly_url'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if (!mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "page does not exist";
    die();
} else {
    echo "page exist";
}
```

My end goal is to check if `file.php` exist, if so redirect to `example.com/file`,
then check if in mysql friendly_url exist, if so - redirect to `example.com/$friendly_url`
else
echo "page does not exist";

***Both .htaccess blocks works, but only if one is deleted.***

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ friendly_url.php?friendly_url=$1
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

Reverse the two rules and instead of checking that the request does *not* map to a file in the second rule, check that the corresponding `.php` exists before rewriting.

For example, try the following instead:

```
# Rewrite to ".php" file if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Otherwise root requests to "friendly.php" instead
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ friendly_url.php?friendly_url=$1 [L]
```

The `\w` shorthand character class is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

There is no need to backslash-escape literal dots in the regex character class.

---

> My end goal is to check if `file.php` exist, if so redirect to
> `example.com/file`, then check if in mysql friendly_url exist, if so -
> redirect to `example.com/$friendly_url` else echo "page does not
> exist";

This is basically what the above rules now do. However, it's not possible to check if the MySQL friendly_url exists in `.htaccess`. Any URL that matches the pattern `^([\w-]+)$` (that doesn't exist as a `.php` file) will be rewritten to `friendly_url.php`. Only URLs that do not match that pattern and do not exist will then drop through to a 404.